# Alternative for Analytical function

Tags: sql, performance, window-functions

I just like to know whether an alternative way is there for the below

Analytical function and  should provide better performance.

```
SELECT last_name FROM 
   (SELECT last_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by department_id ORDER BY last_name) R FROM employees)
   WHERE R =1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Also, make sure to tag the SQL flavor you're using, version included.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "*Analytical function should give better performance compared to analytical function*" doesn't really make sense - at least to me

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to that query without using row_number(). However whilst it will work as an alternative it might not be as efficient as using row_number(). Note he following example is in MySQL bit could be in almost any rdbms:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e76b67/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
    (`Department` varchar(1), `Last_Name` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Employees
    (`Department`, `Last_Name`)
VALUES
    ('a', 'abc'),
    ('a', 'def'),
    ('b', 'ghi')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
e.*
from employees e
left join employees e2 on e.department = e2.department
                      and e.last_name > e2.last_name
where e2.last_name IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e76b67/2/0)**:

```
| Department | Last_Name |
|------------|-----------|
|          a |       abc |
|          b |       ghi |
```